# Error while configuring Snappy. failed with return code 10

Tags: python, snappy

in order to configure snappy I runned the next comand

```
~/snap/bin$ ./snappy-conf /usr/bin/python3.8
```

As a result I got the following error message:

```
Configuring SNAP-Python interface...
java.io.IOException: Python configuration failed.
Command [/usr/bin/python3.8 ./snappyutil.py --snap_home /home/sergio/snap --java_module /home/sergio/snap/snap/modules/org-esa-snap-snap-python.jar --force --log_file ./snappyutil.log --jvm_max_mem 10G --java_home /home/sergio/snap/jre/jre --req_arch amd64]
failed with return code 10.
Please check the log file '/home/sergio/.snap/snap-python/snappy/snappyutil.log'.
    at org.esa.snap.python.PyBridge.configureJpy(PyBridge.java:232)
    at org.esa.snap.python.PyBridge.installPythonModule(PyBridge.java:149)
    at org.esa.snap.rcp.cli.SnapArgsProcessor.processPython(SnapArgsProcessor.java:103)
    at org.esa.snap.rcp.cli.SnapArgsProcessor.process(SnapArgsProcessor.java:49)
    at org.netbeans.modules.sendopts.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:202)
    at org.netbeans.spi.sendopts.Option$1.process(Option.java:387)
    at org.netbeans.api.sendopts.CommandLine.process(CommandLine.java:317)
    at org.netbeans.modules.sendopts.HandlerImpl.execute(HandlerImpl.java:62)
    at org.netbeans.modules.sendopts.Handler.cli(Handler.java:69)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.notifyHandlers(CLIHandler.java:234)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.CLICoreBridge.cli(CLICoreBridge.java:82)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.notifyHandlers(CLIHandler.java:234)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler$1.exec(CLIHandler.java:268)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.finishInitialization(CLIHandler.java:447)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.finishInitialization(MainImpl.java:256)
    at org.netbeans.Main.finishInitialization(Main.java:92)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:316)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Python configuration error: Python configuration failed.
Command [/usr/bin/python3.8 ./snappyutil.py --snap_home /home/sergio/snap --java_module /home/sergio/snap/snap/modules/org-esa-snap-snap-python.jar --force --log_file ./snappyutil.log --jvm_max_mem 10G --java_home /home/sergio/snap/jre/jre --req_arch amd64]
failed with return code 10.
Please check the log file '/home/sergio/.snap/snap-python/snappy/snappyutil.log'.
```

The '/home/sergio/.snap/snap-python/snappy/snappyutil.log' file shows the following info:

```
INFO: Installing from Java module '/home/sergio/snap/snap/modules/org-esa-snap-snap-python.jar'
WARNING: Architecture requirement possibly not met: Python is x86_64 but JVM requires amd64
INFO: Installing jpy...
ERROR: The module 'jpy' is required to run snappy, but no binary 'jpy' wheel matching the pattern
'jpy-{version}-cp38-{abi_tag}-linux_x86_64.whl' could be found.
You can try to build a 'jpy' wheel yourself, then copy it into
"/home/sergio/.snap/snap-python/snappy", and then run the configuration again.
Unzip the jpy sources in /home/sergio/.snap/snap-python/snappy/jpy-<version>.zip, then
  $ cd jpy-<version>
  $ python setup.py bdist_wheel
  $ cp dist/*.whl "/home/sergio/.snap/snap-python/snappy"
Or get the source code from https://github.com/bcdev/jpy and follow the build instructions:
  $ git clone https://github.com/bcdev/jpy.git
  $ cd jpy
ERROR: Configuration failed with exit code 10
```

I downloaded the "jpy" in the "~/.snap/snap-python/snappy" dir but I still have the same error. After looking info about the warning about the Architecture requirements i found that it shouldn't be a problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Thank you so much for your time guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, There was a problem with the python version and snappy. I had to create a conda environment with the 3.6 python version and then use that version on my notebook.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue right now, albeit using  3.6 environment and getting the exact same error. Any tips for one very frustrated person?